# Accesing object value in array of objects by conditioning another object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

This works, but question is can I save the `naziv.value` in `var naziv` in one go, inside this `find method` so I don't have to declare another variable?

```
var naziv = obj.find(c => c.name === "naziv");
console.log(naziv.value)
```

Current output is as it should be `test` by  `console.log(naziv.value)`, I would like to be just `console.log(naziv)`

```js
var obj = [{
    name: "naziv",
    value: "test"
  },
  {
    name: "zzz",
    value: "xxx"
  }
]

var naziv = obj.find(c => c.name === "naziv");
console.log(naziv.value)
```

EDIT:
And also to make an array or values if name is the same, example:

```js
var obj = [{
    name: "naziv",
    value: "test"
  },
  {
    name: "zzz",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    name: "Telefon[]",
    value: "tel1"
  }, {
    name: "Telefon[]",
    value: "tel2"
  }
]

var naziv = obj.find(c => c.name === "Telefon[]");
console.log(naziv.value)
```

Should be: `[tel1,tel2]`

Comment: You are counting on `name` to be unique.
Is there a chance it won't be/test for it not being?

Comment: `var naziv=obj.find(c => c.name === "naziv").value;`

Comment: I, also, like the de-structuring solution by @Abdullah Razzaki.

Comment: @iAmOren Great question, and yes I need that also, to make an array if name is not unique, I edited a question

Comment: Then use `filter`.

Comment: If you want to filter and map in the same iteration, just use a for loop: `const output = []; for(let o of obj) if(o.name === "naziv") output.push(o.value)`

Comment: `var values=obj.filter(item=>item.name=="Telefon[]").map(item=>item.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple values to be as an array, this can be one of the ways

```js
var obj = [{name:"naziv",value:"test"},{name:"zzz",value:"xxx"},{name:"Telefon[]",value:"tel1"},{name:"Telefon[]",value:"tel2"}]

var naziv = obj.filter(c => c.name === "Telefon[]").map(res => res.value);
console.log(naziv)
```

Likewise, if the value is itself is the intended output and if only single value is expected then below is one of the ways. Here, I have used [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
var obj = [{name:"naziv",value:"test"},{name:"zzz",value:"xxx"},{name:"Telefon[]",value:"tel1"}]

var naziv = obj.find(c => c.name === "Telefon[]")?.value;
console.log(naziv)
```

There could be a chance if you need this code to run some older versions of the browsers and there's no support for `Optional Chaining` then below is yet another way

```js
var obj = [{name: "naziv",value: "test"},{name: "zzz",value: "xxx"},{name: "Telefon[]",value: "tel1"}]

var naziv = (obj.find(c => c.name === "Telefon[]") || {}).value;
console.log(naziv)

var notFound = (obj.find(c => c.name === "not_found") || {}).value;
console.log(notFound);
```

Comment: There is no need for `?.` after `filter` as it will never return null or undefined. It will be an empty array if no matches are found

Comment: Yes @adiga. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use de-structuring like `const {value:naziv} = obj.find(c => c.name === "naziv");`

Comment: This is great, never seen that, any help with: to make an array if name is not unique, I edited a question

Comment: You can use `obj.filter(c=>c.name==='naziv').map(c=>c.value)` but that will always be an array

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [{
    name: "naziv",
    value: "test"
  },
  {
    name: "zzz",
    value: "xxx"
  },
  {
    name: "naziv",
    value: "xxx"
  }
]

var naziv = obj.filter(item => item.name === 'naziv').map(item => item.value)
console.log(naziv)
```